# How does one embed IIRB inside of a IronRuby program?

Tags: ruby, ironruby, irb

In Ruby main, you can embed IRB inside of a Ruby script as described [here](http://jameskilton.com/2009/04/02/embedding-irb-into-your-ruby-application/). Is there a way to do something similar with IIRB inside an IronRuby script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.github.com/ironruby/ironruby/debugging might be useful to you ("repl binding" is the same as the one above, I believe, and is what I use).

Comment: We're using that exact `repl(binding)` class right now, but we want to drop into actual IIRB for a few reasons, mainly multiline support. Thanks for your response, though!

Comment: the code you mention should work in ironruby then--does it not?

Comment: It doesn't quite work in IronRuby because it makes use of the Ruby IRB class, but we couldn't find an equivalent IIRB class.

Comment: seems to work fine here: http://gist.github.com/568628 what IIRB class are you referring to?